# Why is day() function throwing me this error: Check for missing argument or incorrect argument data type in call to function 'day'?

Tags: matlab, function, date, datetime, exception

Having this long task that I will resume:

Perform a regression model over the normalized active cases in China using the model.....(long assignment that I'm not worried about and will save you time). **Tip: To convert from datetime to a numeric variable for the regression, use `x=day(date-min(date(:)))+1;` being “date” the datetime vector return from getdata function.**

This is what I have:

```
function RP_ejercicio1

    data = readtable('COVID-19.csv');
    [active_res, confirmed_res, death_res, recovered_res, date]  = getdata(data, 'China', 93/147);

    x=day(date-min(date(:)))+1;
    y = active_res;
    yp = log(y./x);
    a = [x ones(size(x))];
    sol = inv(a'*a)*(a'*yp);
    b = sol(1);
    c = sol(2);
    a = exp(c);

end
```

I get this error: `Check for missing argument or incorrect argument data type in call to function 'day'.` In this line: `x=day(date-min(date(:)))+1;`. The one that is supposed to help as a tip is giving me a headache. I can ensure that `date` is a 1x50 datetime array after executing the getdata function.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the tip wrong? And if it's the second case, is there other way to do the same?

I add an image for more clarity:

[Date array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XbG1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As somebody said [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/513245-why-is-day-function-throwing-me-this-error-check-for-missing-argument-or-incorrect-argument-data), you should be using the function `days`.

Comment: I forgot to write the feedback from the official Mathwork forum. Thank you for remembering it, I choose your answer as the good one because it redirects to the actual solution that I'm using.